# Windows SSH Client to monitor connection

Tags: ssh, connection, putty, ssh-tunnel

I am looking for a Windows SSH Client that will monitor your SSH connection to your Server and will notify you via balloon notification if SSH connection dropped. Also it will let you reconnect automatically. Any programs out there like this?

I use Plink command tool as well as Putty, but if connection fails or times out I get a unfriendly notification and I have to manually try to reconnect. Which works, but their has to be something better!

Comment: I guess this'll sound horribly douchey, but I suspect it doesn't exist on account of people who use SSH avoid windows. Probably also not true. Sigh. I guess, I don't know a good answer for you AND I have emotional trauma from years of using that platform. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a fork of Putty called [PuttyTray](https://puttytray.goeswhere.com/). Amongst others features, it has this one that might interest you:

```
Reconnects on connection failure, including when waking up from stand-by
```

Please give it a try and tell me if it suits your need ;-)

Comment: Does provide a tray icon, but it has more options!

Comment: Wish I could hide the terminal. Don't need the terminal, if I am calling putty.exe from command line

Answer (score 1):

Within Linux, these functionalities are provided by a package called **autossh**. Something equivalent to this exists in Windows too, even though not through the ever-popular Putty application.

On the one hand, there is *autossh* within Cygwin. This is extremely close to the Linux code, and you can find instructions on how to set it up [here](http://www.matthanger.net/2008/04/creating-persistent-ssh-tunnels-in.html). The upside of this is the very same as its downside: you have to install Cygwin. Cygwin is a fantastic program, aimed at recreating a Posix-compliant environment inside Windows. Many people use it daily, but if you do not have specific needs, you may find as excessively complicated to achieve an otherwise attainable goal. Still, if you are into greatly improving your ability to do things inside Windows, I warmly recommend it.

A more agile alternative is [MyEnTunnel](http://nemesis2.qx.net/pages/MyEnTunnel) (=My Encrypted Tunnel). MyEnTunnel [image]

uses PLink to monitor the connection to a remote side. Should this fail, it will automatically reconnect. [image]

The cute thing about MyEnTunnel is that is not disjoint from Putty: as a matter of fact, it can also use Putty sessions, a nd Putty-generated cryptographic keys. Which, in my view, is a definite advantage if you are already using Putty.